# restricting regex code in Notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have a database compiled with Notepad++. After some 10000 records (lines) I decided to add an extra one in the database to separate City, which includes the state The field "City looks like this “Dallas TX” and I wanted it in TWO columns “Dallas” “TX”.

For instance
from
CR.jpg,Courtyard,USA,St George UT,y,n,n

to
CR.jpg,Courtyard,USA,St George, UT,y,n,n

Notice the comma after St George

I needed to REPLACE the SPACE between City and State with a COMMA

and I achieved that in Notepad by searching `[ \t]+` and replacing with

```
,
```

but… a problem remains: in cities like New York I do not want a comma in between New and York.

Is there a way of coding to restrict the adding of the comma ONLY when it appears JUST before two capital letters, e.g. TX, NY, NV, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
\s([A-Z]{2},)
```

With

```
,$1
```

This looks for a space, exactly two letters, and a comma. It replaces the space with a comma and leaves the rest alone.

Here's a **[working demo](https://regex101.com/r/bM3zM6/1)**.

Comment: @josmith can you explain what you mean by that? "Did not accept" it how?

Comment: Sorry, yes the Search query was accepted but it is still placing commas in between the name of the cities. I am testing on a short version and get lines like this with your code: San,Antonio,TX,n,y,y. I guess it must be 2 CAPITAL LETTERS

Comment: @josmith those must be from what you tried to do previously. Unless you copied my regex incorrectly, it's impossible for it to do what you described.

Comment: Note: the `\s` is very important; it's not just `s`.

Comment: My apologies! I'm on my knees! You are absolutely right; I had it screwed up before I started. It worked like a charm! Many thanks

Comment: @josmith Glad to help! Please remember to select an answer! :)

Comment: How do I select an answer?

Comment: @josmith there's a check mark next to my answer, at the top. Click on it, and it will turn green. :)

Comment: There's no check mark. I clicked on "votes" next to active and oldest. Also on the left on the arrow that turned 0 into 1. is that it?

Comment: @josmith thanks for the upvote! But the check mark is different; it's underneath the arrows. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @josmith Ha! Thanks!